# How to Display CPT Posts on index Page

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I have created Custom Post type called "Natural Food" and displays the Post of this CPT Under

> Natural Food

Menu, my index page also contains some post, as well as i want to display "Natural Food" post in index page how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function hooked to [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) which modifies `post_type` argument of the main query to add your custom post type.

```
function wpd_home_post_types( $query ){
    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'natural_food' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_home_post_types' );
```

Comment: you fix not working, see my answer it's working, additionally i added 'book' in $query->set for display 'book' CPT in the index page, see my answer if it contains any errors then add comment

Answer (score -2):

This code also worked for me. 
Added `!is_admin` to Prevent view WP Dashboard

```
   function wpd_home_post_types( $query ){
        if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
            if ( $query->is_home ) {
                $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'natural-foods' ) );   
            }

        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_home_post_types' );
```